# Linux terminal style Tab autocompletion in Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I type `document.q` several suggestions popup and when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it accepts the first suggestion, I need to press <kbd>⬇</kbd> key several times to pick the desired. I'm not a fan of <kbd>⬇</kbd> key. I'm a fan of an autocompletion found in a Linux terminal. Say there are following directories in CWD.

```
musicold
musicvideos
musicvideoshot
```

`cd m` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it will find only `music` part, and then you type `v` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it'll find `musicvideos`  etc.

Couldn't find such a setting in Vscode version 1.19.0.

Comment: Doesn't just typing "document.qsa get you to document.querySelectorAll with no need to arrow key?  The suggestions use fuzzy search.  But I don't know if there is a way or an extension to enable fuzzy search in the terminal though.

Comment: @Mark, thats even better. Thank you. I'll accept your answer if you turn your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick suggestions do use fuzzy search so you can type "document.qsa" and get to "document.querySelectorAll" for example quite fast.